# Different way to generate divs via checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Currently I am using the below method using JS to generate a block of text in a right column when a check box is clicked ticked in a left column.

This has been working fine, however each time I need to add a check box, I need to add a new class and new formContainer element. With the original 3 I had, wasn't a big deal. But now that I'm up to 10 and growing, getting a bit cumbersome.

What better possibilities exist to generate a div/block of text on a different part of the page as a result of a ticked check box?

**Check Box**

```
 <input id="chk" data-detail="<br>Right 1" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />1
```

**Creating individual class**

```
  <div class="formContainer"></div>
```

**Script**

```
 <script>
 $('.chkbox').on('click',function(){
if($(this).is(':checked'))
{
   $('.formContainer').html('<div      class="new">'+$(this).data('detail')+'</div>');
}
else
{
    $('.formContainer').html('');
}
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your need and the content of the divs I got a couple of suggestions :

1. Modal popups. If you these divs are just notifications then a popup would do (but doubt this is what you need).
2. List group, use bootstrap's neat class [list group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group) to show the needed info in an `<ul>` element, the JS that comes with these can be neat as well with special animations.
3. Use [tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)  on each checkbox instead of getting a whole div appearing.
4. Last suggestion which I like least is putting all of your div's in a single container div on the right. Fix its width and height and set overflow attribute so you can scroll up and down the shown divs

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting them in columns you can generate them using bootstrap gridsystem.

```
<div class="formContainer>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-m-4"></div>
    <div class="col-m-4"></div>
    <div class="col-m-4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div> 
</div>
```

If you are wanting to keep them in the same column you could just use .append()

```
$('.formContainer').append('<div      class="new">'+$(this).data('detail')+'</div>');
```

These can be used together to generate a fluid system or just the append can be used to keep adding divs to your formContainer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest appending a form after your checkbox using the Jquery function .after(newElement);

[Play with it on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZWPqZ?editors=1010)

Html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .formContainer{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
</style>  

<label class="checkboxLabel">
  <input class="checkboxesThatAppends" type="checkbox" value="results" />
  Show me a form
</label>

<label class="checkboxLabel">
  <input class="checkboxesThatAppends" type="checkbox" value="results" />
  Show me a form
</label>

<label class="checkboxLabel">
  <input class="checkboxesThatAppends" type="checkbox" value="results" />
  Show me a form
</label>

<label class="checkboxLabel">
  <input class="checkboxesThatAppends" type="checkbox" value="results" />
  Show me a form
</label>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.checkboxesThatAppends').click(function(){
    var associatedFormId = $(this).attr('data-associated-form-id');
    if(associatedFormId){
      //if there is a form container associated with this checkbox already
      //then let's remove that form.
      //and remove the association from the checkbox
      $('#'+associatedFormId).remove();
      $(this).attr('data-associated-form-id', '');
    }else{
      //generate an Id for the new form to attach.
      var newId = new Date().getTime();
      $(this).attr('data-associated-form-id', newId);
      $(this).parent().after('<div id="'+newId+'" class="formContainer"></div> ');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: I think that `change` event would be better than click. Then it is good to use JavaScript `this.checked` to determine if checkbox was checked.

Comment: @EchoSin you are right, on change and checkmark check would be the most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery's [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) methods in combination with wrapping HTML elements to achieve this effect.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/xuc4tze0/1/

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input id="chk" data-detail="Right 1" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input id="chk" data-detail="Right 2" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <input id="chk" data-detail="Right 3" class="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="results" />3
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.left, .right {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

**Javascript / jQuery**

```
$('.chkbox').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
    // Find the row and add the 'right' column
    $(this).closest('.row').append('<div class="right">' + $(this).data('detail') + '</div>');
  } else {
    // Find the 'right' column and remove it
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.right').remove();
  }
});
```